# How to use max for two tables

Tags: mysql

I want use `MAX` on a time field, it works but the value is "0"

This query is before I use `MAX`:

```
SELECT a.`JAM`, AVG(a.PacketLoss) AVG
FROM (
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPATH_PM` AS PHB,`VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS` AS PacketLoss, `VSIPPMRttMeans` AS Latency, 'IPPM'
FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPATH_PM` LIKE '%AF31%'
UNION
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPOOL_PM`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMForwardDrop-Means`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMRttMeans`, 'IPPOOLPM'
FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas` 
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPOOL_PM` LIKE '%AF31%') a
GROUP BY a.`JAM`
LIMIT 10000
```

output here

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnIAH.png)

Then I use `MAX` here

```
SELECT a.`JAM`, AVG(a.PacketLoss) AVG
FROM (
SELECT MAX(JAM) AS JAM,`RNC`,`IPPATH_PM` AS PHB,`VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS` AS PacketLoss, `VSIPPMRttMeans` AS Latency, 'IPPM'
FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPATH_PM` LIKE '%AF31%'
UNION
SELECT MAX(JAM) AS JAM,`RNC`,`IPPOOL_PM`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMForwardDrop-Means`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMRttMeans`, 'IPPOOLPM'
FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas` 
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPOOL_PM` LIKE '%AF31%') a
GROUP BY a.`JAM`
LIMIT 10000
```

[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H8Vb.png)

I expected the output is last time with the value, can someone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the `MAX` on your outer query, not the inner one. When you take it on the inner queries, MySQL gives you an indeterminate value of the non-aggregated columns e.g. `VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS`, which appears to be a 0 value for your sample data. Change your query to:

```
SELECT MAX(a.`JAM`), AVG(a.PacketLoss) AVG
FROM (
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPATH_PM` AS PHB,`VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS` AS PacketLoss, `VSIPPMRttMeans` AS Latency, 'IPPM'
FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPATH_PM` LIKE '%AF31%'
UNION
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPOOL_PM`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMForwardDrop-Means`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMRttMeans`, 'IPPOOLPM'
FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas` 
WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPOOL_PM` LIKE '%AF31%') a
```

Note the `GROUP BY` is no longer required since you are taking the `MAX` and the `AVG` over the whole data set, and the `LIMIT` is not required as this query will only produce 1 row.